# If $T$ is a linear operator, then what does $T^2=0$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

My teacher has this exercise in his notes:

$$\text{Let }T\in\mathcal{L}(V).\text{ Prove that }T^2=0\Leftrightarrow\text{Im}(T)\subseteq\text{Ker}(T).\tag{*}\label{*}$$
where $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the set of all linear maps $V\to V$, and $\text{Ker}(T)=${$x\in V\mid T(x)=0$}. My teacher did not specify what the $0$ in $\eqref{*}$ means. Can anyone help me understand what he might mean with this symbol?

Comment: In this sense, the zero vector. It would be cumbersome to use many different symbols and subscripts for the zero vector in different spaces (and even their zero maps!) so we just write $0.$ I can write a more in-depth answer later.

Comment: Every vector space has a zero element. Here it is the $0$ of $V$.

Comment: Both of the previous comments aren't fully correct. $0$ in the first formula is the zero-element of $\mathcal{L}(V)$. That is the linear map $V \to V$ which is constant $0$. (In the definition of the kernel it is the zero vector of $V$, as the previous comments noted.)

Comment: So "$0$" in the first formula is the linear map $0\colon V\to V$ with $0(x)=0,\,\forall x\in V$?

Comment: @SomeBoringDude: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If you know anything about algebraic structures, it might be helpful to see this as an instance of the more general theorem(s) (inversely, if you don't know about monoids, it might be best to skip this): "If $(M,\cdot,e)$ is a monoid, then $(\operatorname{End}(M),\circ,\mathbf{id})$, the set of homomorphisms $M\to M$ under composition, is also a monoid.  If we define $\mathbf{e} : M \to M$ by $\mathbf{e}(x) = e$ for every $x\in M$, then $\mathbf{e} \in \operatorname{End}(M)$. For every $T \in \operatorname{End}(M)$, we have $T^2 = \mathbf{e} \iff \operatorname{im}(T) \subseteq \ker(T)$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the statement “$T^2=0\iff\operatorname{Im}(T)\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(T)$”, the symbol $0$ refers to the zero map $\phi:V\to V$ such that $\phi(v)=\vec 0$ for all $v\in V$, where $\vec 0$ is the additive identity element of the vector space $V$.

This notation might seem injudicious to you, but it is not without merit. In any vector space, it is common to denote its additive identity element by $0$, even when the elements of that vector space happen to be functions, sets, matrices, etc. rather than elements of (say) $\mathbb R^n$. Why is this relevant? If $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$, then $L(V)$ is itself a vector space over $K$, and the zero map is its additive identity. As a result, it is customary to denote this map by $0$. If there are multiple vector spaces under consideration, then it is usually clear from context which $0$ is meant. For instance, in your case, $T^2$ is the linear map obtained by composing $T$ with itself, and so it would be absurd for $0$ to denote the additive identity of $V$, rather than $L(V)$; in general, the members of a vector space $V$ are not linear maps.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of linear maps, $0$ represents the zero vector, denoted as $(\mathbf{0})$, which is the additive identity element in the vector space $V$. It is the vector that satisfies the property $(\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{v})$ for any vector $(\mathbf{v})$ in $V$.

In the given exercise, $T^2 = \mathbf{0}$ means that the composition of the linear map $T$ with itself results in the zero map, denoted as $(\mathbf{0})$, which maps every vector in $V$ to the zero vector.

$Im(T)$ represents the image of the linear map $T$, the subspace consisting of vectors that $T$ can map to. $Ker(T)$ represents the kernel of $T$, the subspace consisting of vectors that $T$ maps to the zero vector.

The statement $T^2 = \mathbf{0}$ implies $Im(T) \subseteq Ker(T)$ means that if $T$ composed with itself is the zero map, then every vector in the image of $T$ is also in the kernel of $T$. In other words, the image of $T$ is a subset of the kernel of $T$.

To prove this, assume $T^2 = \mathbf{0}$ and show that for any vector $x$ in $Im(T)$, $T(x) = \mathbf{0}$. This demonstrates that the image of $T$ is indeed contained within the kernel of $T$.

It's always recommended to clarify any symbol or notation ambiguity with your teacher for a precise understanding of their intended meaning.

**HOPE THAT HELPS**

Comment: So $T^2$ is $T\circ T$...? My god I thought it was a product of the function $T$ with itself! We really need some universal math notation.

Comment: Well, composition of linear maps on finitie dimensional vector spaces is matrix multiplication, so it would make sense for $T^2(x) = T(T(x)).$

Comment: @SomeBoringDude What would $T(v)T(v)$ even mean for general vectors spaces?

Comment: @MathematicallyInterested  Did not even think about that, now it makes a bit more sense.